# INDEX & MATCH issue

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have lists on 2 sheets in Excel. On my customers sheet I have this information:

```
 Cus    Name
 352445 Mr A Person
 352445 Mrs B Wife
 352448 Mr B Someone
 352448 Mr Another Guy
 352448 Mr Who What
 352448 Mr Tall Man
 352448 Mr Big Man
 352448 Mr Yet Another
 352450 Mr Top Dude
 352450 Mr Bad Dude
 352450 Mr Foreign Guy
 352452 Mr Local Man
 352452 Mrs High Scorer
```

On my target data sheet I have a list of customer numbers:

```
Cust
352437
352438
352438
352445
352445
352445
352448
352448
352448
352448
352448
352448
352450
352450
352450
352452
352452
352452
352452
```

I have been trying to use INDEX & MATCH to populate the names from the customer sheet into my target sheet

so I tried:

```
=MATCH(A2,'Participants Data'!$A$2:$A$674,1)
```

which puts **1** for *352437*, **2** for all instances of *352438*,**3** for *352445*, **4** for *352448*

Then I tried using `INDEX('Participants Data'!$B$2:$B$674,MATCH(A2,'Participants Data'!$A$2:$A$674,0))` and copying that down.

The problem is that I get this:

```
Cust    Name
352445  Mr A Person
352445  Mr A Person
352445  Mr A Person
352448  Mr B Someone
352448  Mr B Someone
352448  Mr B Someone
352448  Mr B Someone
```

...

when it should be (or rather, what I am trying to achieve):

```
 352445 Mr A Person
 352445 Mrs B Wife
 352448 Mr B Someone
 352448 Mr Another Guy
 352448 Mr Who What
 352448 Mr Tall Man
 352448 Mr Big Man
 352448 Mr Yet Another
```

so what am I doing wrong in my `INDEX` & `MATCH` ?

Comment: It's giving you the correct result?  The way you have it written, it will return the first result for all matches.  What is your desired output?

Comment: The MATCH() function matches the search value with the first occurence of it in the search range. The first customer with No *352445* is *Mr A Person*, the answer depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I want the different names for the customer numbers, so for `352448` there should be 5 different names from the *Customers* sheet - but I need to try and use some other functions like `Small` I guess in order to get the first smallest, 2nd smallest etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find `Nth` occurrence of a value in a table, you can can use the following array formula (enter in A2, confirm with Ctrl+shift+Enter, and fill the rest of the range):

```
 =INDEX(ColB,SMALL(IF(ColA=A2,ROW(ColA)-MIN(ROW(ColA))+1,1E+100),COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)))
```

Where `ColA` and `ColB` are the ranges in customer sheet. `COUNTIF` part calculates `N`.

Comment: Thanks, is this to go on the target sheet, so *ColB = B:B*, *ColA = A:A* etc?

Comment: @Our Man In Bananas I have updated the formula slightly. This formula should go on the target sheet, so `ColA` should be `'Participants Data'!$A$2:$A$674`